# Expression For $u_{n+1}=u_n^2+u_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the formula of the sequence
>   $$u_1=a, u_{n+1}=u_n^2+u_n$$

Is there a "simple" formula for the sequence ?

Comment: This is called a quadratic map.  The standard form comes from making the substitution $u_n = v_n - 1/2$ to get $v_{n+1} = v_n{}^2 + 1/4$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple formula for $u_n$ in terms of $a$. Indeed, $u_n$ is a polynomial expression on $a$ of degree $2^{n-1}$.

If you seek a simple formula for $u_n$ to understand its convergence, then this is hopeless because convergence is explained by Julia sets, which are quite complicated. In this case, the Julia set of $f(z)=z^2+z$:

[image]

(Image computed with [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=julia+set+z%5E2%2Bz))